# Getting Error "react_devtools_backend.js:2560 AudioContext error at decodeAudioData for /static/media/mysong.mp3" at my hosting website

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I used react P5.sound for creating the music player. And I wrote the code at the preload function.

```
import mysong from "./localsongs/mysong.mp3";

preload() {
         p5.loadSound(mysong);
}
```

This code really works fine on the local and plays the music.
But when I hosted on the server and deploy the website, I got the error that I've mentioned in the title.

I tried the loadSound function for loadsound like

```
preload() {
         p5.loadSound(url("./localsongs/mysong.mp3));
}
```

But in this case, the error

```
url is not defined
```

is got in my react console.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you meant something like:

```
let mysong;

preload() {
   mysong = loadSound("./localsongs/mysong.mp3");
}
```

For more info see [`loadSound()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadSound).

You might need to serve the mp3 file on a [local webserver](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server)